# Where is it method defined in jasmine

Tags: jasmine

I want to add a print in `it` method so that it prints the name of the spec. Where is `it` defined? I tried to look for the method's implementation but couldn't find it.

Comment: So the question is you want to extend `it` function and add your `print` function inside it?

Comment: you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `describe` and `it` (xdescribe, fdescribe and so on as well) are defined in `Env.js` as you can see [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/8a731e17a7e4d97c73ba8428911c4f6d3a004c23/src/core/Env.js#L1090)

Now, in order to *enhance* `it` (no pun intended) you'd either have to override it or even provide your own wrapper in a global namespace and use that one.